# Simplest screenshot software

Tags: software-recommendation

Mainly for making tutorials, on windows.

The simpler, the better. If it could just kinda like on mac. So that I can select an area. And if I could easily annote after taking the picture, that'd be awesome too.

Answer (score 4):

[**Snipping tool**](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows-vista/Use-Snipping-Tool-to-capture-screen-shots) comes with every Windows from Vista to above† and has about the same options as Grab + Preview combo on OS X; including annotating capabilities.

While I was on XP (or on Vista not knowing the existence of Snipping tool) I've found [**Lightscreen**](http://lightscreen.sourceforge.net/) as an easy, simple and lightweight capture tool. In matter of a fact, I carry a [**portable version** of Lightscreen](http://portableapps.com/apps/utilities/lightscreen_portable) on my USB-stick, just in case. Lightscreen lacks annotating options, though.

*† Not included with Home Basic nor Starter editions, though.*

Comment: Unfortunately snipping tool wasn't included with Windows Vista Home Basic. not sure what the situation is for Windows 7

Comment: @Jaips, oh, true. With 7, it seems Snipping tool isn't included with Home Basic nor Starter. Thanks!

Comment: OK, found snipping tool, thanks. But can I add text with it? Lightscreen seems like a cool alternative. Thanks a lot dude

Answer (score 1):

I usually end up doing Shift + "Print Screen" (usually same button as "SysRq"). Open Paint / Photoshop / etc. and paste it into a new file. Doesn't let you select areas of the screen but I usually refine the edges in Photoshop anyway. Also, it's free since it's built into Windows.

Answer (score 1):

I really like [Screensnapr](http://www.screensnapr.com/), which also lets you upload screenshots automatically

Answer (score 0):

At work they installed [Snagit](http://www.techsmith.com/snagit/default.asp) which I am strongly considering getting for home. Although I've always relied on the good ol' Printscreen+paste in Photoshop approach before, it is really convenient to have some image editing capabilities (cropping, drawing semi-transparent highlights, etc.) in the screenshot software.